# How to render json with arbitrary keys using mustache?

Tags: ruby, templates, mustache

I have a JSON object that looks like the following:

```
{
    "XXX":{"name":"First"},
    "YYY":{"name":"Second"},
    ....
}
```

I need to render it to look like:

```
<div>
    <h1>XXX</h1>
    <p>First</p>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>YYY</h1>
    <p>Second</p>
</div>
....
```

How will I accomplish this using [Mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache#readme)? The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to reference the items because the key names are arbitrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the JSON to a hash using your favorite JSON parser, that will give you something that looks like this:

```
json = {
    "XXX" => {"name" => "First"},
    "YYY" => {"name" => "Second"},
    "ZZZ" => {"name" => "Third"}
}
```

Then simply rearrange it into a list of little hashes with known keys:

```
for_mustache = json.keys.inject([ ]) do |a, k|
    a.push({ :k => k, :v => json[k]['name']})
    a
end
```

There are probably cleverer ways to do that above. Now you'll have something simple and regular like this in `for_mustache`:

```
[
    { :k => "XXX", :v => "First"  },
    { :k => "YYY", :v => "Second" },
    { :k => "ZZZ", :v => "Third"  }
]
```

Then you can handle that data structure just like any other array of hashes in Mustache:

```
{{#for_mustache}}
    <div>
        <h1>{{k}}</h1>
        <p>{{v}}</p>
    </div>
{{/for_mustache}}
```

Comment: Is that hash intended to be json?

Comment: If it's intended to be JS, I think the syntax you want is:        json = {
    XXX: {"name":"First"},
    YYY: {"name":"Second"},
    ZZZ: {"name": "Third"}
}

Comment: @morefromalan: Sorry, missed the [tag:ruby] tag. There are Mustache template engines for many languages.