# parse JSON with Mustache on Android

Tags: android, json, mustache

I'm reading an array of JSON objects from an API, and hope to use Mustache to display the data in a nice HTML format.

I downloaded the [pre-built .jar file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/samskivert/jmustache/1.3/jmustache-1.3.jar) from https://github.com/samskivert/jmustache, and ran the hello world with no problem:

```
String text = "One, two, {{three}}. Three sir!";
Template tmpl = Mustache.compiler().compile(text);
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("three", "five");
Log.d("json",tmpl.execute(data));
```

How do I feed my JSONObject to Mustache?

I tried this:

```
JSONObject eventJSON = events.getJSONObject(event_count);
String text = "<h1>{{summary}}</h1>";
Template tmpl = Mustache.compiler().compile(text);
Log.d("this breaks", tmpl.execute(eventJSON));
```

Logcat says `"No key, method or field with name 'summary' on line 1"`

I get the same error when sending a JSON string:

```
Log.d("this breaks", tmpl.execute(eventJSON.toString()));
```

eventJSON.toString() results in a [really long string](http://pastebin.com/DmgMXu1f) that starts

```
{"summary":"the LUSTER a.k.a. VJ WADAKENによるウィークデーモンスターパーティー。\r\n","invitations":[],"genres":[1,2],"open_date":"2011-11-17"...
```

Do I have to [convert the JSON to a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5565948/how-to-render-json-with-arbitrary-keys-using-mustache/5570022#5570022)?

Logcat full error:

```
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227): Caused by: com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException: No key, method or field with name 'summary' on line 1
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$VariableSegment.execute(Mustache.java:520)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.executeSegs(Template.java:70)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.execute(Template.java:58)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.execute(Template.java:48)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at com.example.android.events.AsyncJSONEventParser.parseEventJSON(AsyncJSONEventParser.java:88)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at com.example.android.events.AsyncJSONEventParser.doInBackground(AsyncJSONEventParser.java:40)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at com.example.android.events.AsyncJSONEventParser.doInBackground(AsyncJSONEventParser.java:1)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
11-17 12:04:19.080: E/AndroidRuntime(17227):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The json can't be used as a string and does need to be a hash... I do that like so with Jackson. See this [post about jackson parsing in 5 minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected void parseJsonString(String json){
    try {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Object root = mapper.readValue(json, Object.class);
        //Map<String,String> rootAsMap = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
        //rails 3.0.3 is bad and doesn't qoute strings
        userData = (Map<String,Object>) mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```